# Rank and date change case expression

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show the second part below. If a person goes from high to low it is good but if they go from low to high it is bad. Any ideas on how I'd accomplish this? I have the SQL to return the top part but not sure how to get the second part.

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. But, for starters, since you "have the sql to return the top part," you might want to post that?

Comment: For membno 1234 it goes from 4 to 3 so good and 6789 goes from 3 to 4 which is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you propably looking for [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```
select membno, rancs, date_rank
, case 
   when lag(rancs, 1, rancs) over (partition by membno order by date_rank) > rancs then 'GOOD' 
   when lag(rancs, 1, rancs) over (partition by membno order by date_rank) < rancs then 'BAD'
   else 'i do''n know'
   end second_part_for_current_row
from something
```

for global resoult use self join:

```
select curr.membno, prev.rancs, curr.rancs
, case 
   when prev.rancs > curr.rancs then 'GOOD' 
   when prev.rancs < curr.rancs then 'BAD'
   else 'i do''n know'
   end second_part
from something curr 
left join something prev on curr.membno = prev.membno and curr.date_rank = prev.date_rank + 1
where not exists (select 1 from something pres where pres.membno = curr.membno and curr.date_rank + 1 = pres.date_rank)
```